# PHP / PDF upload

Tags: php, user-interface, pdf

I have searched all over the internet on the possibility to upload a pdf file using php script. I tried all the suggestions given in this site and it didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Uploaded</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//ini_set("upload_max_filesize", 10000000);
$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
//$allowed_ext = "pdf";
//$max_size = "9000000000000000000000";
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 0);
echo "<p>";
if((($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "image/png" )
  || ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
  || ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "application/msword")
  || ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
  || ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "text/plain")
  || ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "application/wordperfect6.0")
  || ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "application/pdf"))
  && ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"] < 10000000))
  {

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
}     else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}
  }
echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";  
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you even know what you're doing?

Comment: So is the problem that the uploaded PDF file is not matching the MIME type you have (`application/pdf`)?

Comment: There are a number of things that could be going wrong here. You should do some debugging to find out at what point it fails. Add an `echo "1";` or something to your first if-statement and an `echo "2";` to your second if-statement and an `echo "3";` to your else-statement. Then you can find out what path it's taking to see where your failure is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to print the type recongnized of your file in the else statement instead of simply printing "Upload failed".

```
echo ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]);
```

Maybe the tyope recognized is not one belonging to the types specified in the if.

Comment: pdf file is not matching (application/pdf)

Comment: pdf file is not matching (application/pdf): fix it by adding a new conditions in the if statement: print the type recognized with echo($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]) and insert it into new if statement with another || conditions.                     to check wheter a file already exist use php function exist: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php. For example before the move_uploaded_file do something like: if(file_exists($uploadfile)) rename else move_upload_file

Comment: To rename simply: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile."something new")  For example you can set the current timestamp instead of something new but you got the point

Comment: :) you are welcome! so please flag my answer as the correct one! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this on the project I'm currently working on. Here is the upload code I use.

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'upload.php';

// Initialize file path
define ('UPLOAD_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . pdfFolder/");

// list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
$allowedExtensions = array("pdf", "xls");

// max file size in bytes
$sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

$uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);

$result = $uploader->handleUpload(UPLOAD_PATH, false);

if(sizeof($result['error']) == 0){
    // do what you want on success
}
else{
    echo "Error - " . $result['error'];
}
```

Here is the uploaded.php file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Handle file uploads via XMLHttpRequest
 */
class qqUploadedFileXhr {
    /**
     * Save the file to the specified path
     * @return boolean TRUE on success
     */
    function save($path) {    
        $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
        $temp = tmpfile();
//      $temp = fopen("php://temp", "wb");
        $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
        fclose($input);

        if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){            
            return false;
        }

        $target = fopen($path, "w");        
        fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
        fclose($target);

        return true;
    }
    function getName() {
        return $_GET['qqfile'];
    }
    function getSize() {
        if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"])){
            return (int)$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"];            
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Getting content length is not supported.');
        }      
    }   
}

/**
 * Handle file uploads via regular form post (uses the $_FILES array)
 */
class qqUploadedFileForm {  
    /**
     * Save the file to the specified path
     * @return boolean TRUE on success
     */
    function save($path) {
        if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function getName() {
        return $_FILES['file']['name'];
    }
    function getSize() {
        return $_FILES['file']['size'];
    }
}

class qqFileUploader {
    private $allowedExtensions = array();
    private $sizeLimit = 10485760;
    private $file;

    function __construct(array $allowedExtensions = array(), $sizeLimit = 10485760){        
        $allowedExtensions = array_map("strtolower", $allowedExtensions);

        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;        
        $this->sizeLimit = $sizeLimit;

        $this->checkServerSettings();       

        if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
            $this->file = new qqUploadedFileXhr();
        } elseif (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
            $this->file = new qqUploadedFileForm();
        } else {
            $this->file = false; 
        }
    }

    private function checkServerSettings(){        
        $postSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
        $uploadSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));        

        if ($postSize < $this->sizeLimit || $uploadSize < $this->sizeLimit){
            $size = max(1, $this->sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) . 'M';             
            die("{'error':'increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to $size'}");    
        }        
    }

    private function toBytes($str){
        $val = trim($str);
        $last = strtolower($str[strlen($str)-1]);
        switch($last) {
            case 'g': $val *= 1024;
            case 'm': $val *= 1024;
            case 'k': $val *= 1024;        
        }
        return $val;
    }

    /**
     * Returns array('success'=>true) or array('error'=>'error message')
     */
    function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $resample, $replaceOldFile = TRUE){
        if (!is_writable($uploadDirectory)){
            if (!mkdir($uploadDirectory, 0777, true)) {
                die('Failed to create folders...');
                return array('error' => "Server error. Upload directory isn't writable." . $uploadDirectory);
            }
        }

        if (!$this->file){
            return array('error' => 'No files were uploaded.');
        }

        $size = $this->file->getSize();

        if ($size == 0) {
            return array('error' => 'File is empty');
        }

        if ($size > $this->sizeLimit) {
            return array('error' => 'File is too large');
        }

        $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->file->getName());
        $filename = $pathinfo['filename'];
        //$filename = md5(uniqid());
        $ext = $pathinfo['extension'];

        if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $this->allowedExtensions)){
            $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
            return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
        }

        if(!$replaceOldFile){
            /// don't overwrite previous files that were uploaded
            while (file_exists($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)) {
                $filename .= rand(10, 99);
            }
        }

        if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
                'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered.');
        }
    }    
}
```

Hope this helps!